# creating a web test for a web application in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, integration-testing

I'm trying to test a simple web application but cant't get a start.
As far as I know there must be a "create web test" in the dialog for "New Test"...
I have some non ui-tests that work so far in my test application but can't create a web test.
I tried this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182539(v=vs.90).aspx
I reinstalled service pack 1 for vs 2010, tried to run devenv /installvstemplates, and searched in the configuration of my test project and now I'm stuck.
I also read that a special testing version of Visual Studio might be needed, but that seemed to be a former version.

Can someone give me a hand where to start?

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50938 SP1Rel

Comment: Just create Test Project on your solution :D

Comment: Are you using WEbForms or MVC?

Comment: WebForms I believe - its my first :)

Comment: I created a second Test Project, added a "Verweis" (It's a Link or Relation in english I think) to the Web application project - no difference...